Why don't they use golf ball dimples on bullets or cannon balls?
Dimples help the golf ball to fly far. But do you know why they don't use them on bullets or cannon balls?
Some kinds of cannon ball have similar size as a golf ball.

Does this answer your question? Why are golf balls the only (famous) object with dimples?

See also this answer to "Would dimples help a ping pong ball travel faster?". Aside from having just the right Reynolds number for dimples to reduce drag, they also increase magnus lift from the golf ball's backspin, which cannonballs do not have.

Bullets and cannon balls need to form a good seal as they travel down the barrel. They are propelled down the barrel by high pressure gas. If gas gets by, they don't go very far at all.
They also have another problem. Any slight asymmetry causes asymmetric forces from air as they fly. This deflects them from their target in unpredictable directions. To counteract this, bullets and cannon balls are given spin as they travel down the barrel. Asymmetric forces spin with the bullet/cannon ball and average to no deflection.
The way they are given spin is by spiral shaped scratches along the barrel. This is called rifling. Older guns used wadding to help form a seal and impart spin. In newer guns, the large forces during firing make the bullet fit the grooves. Sometimes bullets are made to fit the grooves.
